# Android: Where log cat goes while running on device?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I'm using Eclipse on mac for developing android apps.
When I run the application on emulator the log cat window shows what is expected and do work fine but when I run(or even debug) on real android connected device my log cat window doesn't show even a single line.

How to deal with log cat when running on real android devices?

Thanks,

Comment: did you turn on debuging on your device ?

Comment: Yup!
I did the debugging "ON" on my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select the device in the DDMS environment, Windows tab, select "Devices", and then select your device, i.e. "HtXXXXXXX".

Answer (score 1):

First, Is device really connected? To check whether the device is connected or not, just run **`adb devices`** on console. It will list all the devices attached to the system.

Second, just run the **`adb logcat`** command at the command prompt, it will display the logcat window separately.

While many devices are attached to a system, adb logcat will display the following message:
**- waiting for device -
error: more than one device and emulator**

so to resolve above case, you have to run the command with device id with -s option.

For example:
**`adb -s emulator-5556 logcat`** , this will display the logcat for emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try just to restart it when you connected to device.